# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to store the information that I receive in start to a variable called t and it is not giving me the information.

````
export const LoginScreen = async() => {
  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const start = async function () {
    const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:3003/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': formValues.email,
        'password': formValues.password
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  
    const data = await resp.json();
  
    return data;
  }

  const t = await start();

  console.log(t)

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```
````

Comment: Why did you export an async function as React component?

Comment: Because I am trying to store my information that I receive in data in a variable and I am not being able to do it if I do not await. What would be the correct way?

Comment: `start` async function is enough. Please add whole component file to help

Comment: I already replaced it, but below I have a form that allows me to add the information in email and password. What I want to do is store my fetch information in order to handle my object information

Comment: If I await my variable t, I get the information from `Promise {<pending>}`

Comment: Hi @fanjiooJr, You will have to convert the function to a promise and it's all set

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but how would that be?

Comment: @fanjiooJr, The main problem is that React will only render the components that returns a jsx if being referenced, As you had it as a async function at the start that was causing you the issues, Now as they are removed, the code is working as expected, I have added a working code snippet, that is working in the codesandbox.

Comment: Hi @SARAN i didn't see the snippet :thinking:

Comment: Hi @fanjiooJr, check my answer for the section "CODE UPDATE for SANDBOX link". It is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove async in component delaration and try again:

```
export const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [res, setRes] = useState()
  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const start = async function () {
    const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:3003/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': formValues.email,
        'password': formValues.password
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  
    const data = await resp.json();
  
    return data;
  }

  start().then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
    setRes(res);
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I can't do that, since await is not defined in my variable named t.
But if I remove it, it comes out, `Promise {<pending>}`

Comment: Hi @Daniel, this will not work because the await keywords are only allowed inside async functions.

Comment: If that works excellent for me, but that `res` that I receive as I handle it to be able to unstructured it and use it in my jsx

Comment: @fanjiooJr I updated the answer, does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your async function inside an useEffect() hook to handle side-effects properly. And did you leave out the JSX you want to return on purpose?

```
export const LoginScreen = async() => {
  // --------- EDIT ----------- //
  const [res, setRes] = useState()

  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  // WRAP ASYNC CODE IN USEEFFECT
  useEffect(async() => {
    const start = async function () {
      const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:3003/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'email': formValues.email,
          'password': formValues.password
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      const data = await resp.json();
      return data;
    }

    // ------- EDIT ------- //
    const t = await start().then(res => {
      console.log(res) 
      setRes(res)     
    });           
  }, [])


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  // Not returning any JSX for this react screen component?
  // return (
  //   <View>
  //     ...
  //.  </View>
  // )
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, since I want to store my information received in the promise and then be able to handle it to display it in my jsx. If I have jsx below, just don't put it

Comment: "If I have jsx below, just don't put it" <- Do you mean you do have JSX but you did not include in the question (why?), or this component "LoginScreen" is just a function with no JSX involved? In this case, you should change your component name as it is confusing. Also, for handling async code easily, you can use useState together with useEffect.

Comment: Editted the code for easier usage with useState.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is that you can convert the async function into a promise and it will wait for the execution to complete. The execution with error handling will be as follows.

```js
export const LoginScreen = async () => {
  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const start = function () {
    //   converting into a async promise
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3003/login", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: formValues.email,
            password: formValues.password,
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });

        const data = await resp.json();
        //   resolving on success

        resolve(data);
      } catch (error) {
        //   rejecting on failures
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };

  // Now this will await the start function to be completed.
  const t = await start();

  console.log(t);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
};
```

Explanation : As we are already waiting for inside a async function, JS tends to skip it, unless it is a promise to be resolved explicitly. Thus now converting your function to a Promise we can wait for it to be resolved.

I Made a simple working example for NODE,

```js
const LoginScreen = async () => {
  const start = function () {
    //   converting into a async promise
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        setTimeout(() => {
          return("Hello");
        }, 3000);
      } catch (error) {
        //   rejecting on failures
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };

  const t = await start();

  console.log(t);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
};

LoginScreen();
```

***If you see, the function will now wait for 3 seconds, and then save the data in t, after the start function is resolved***

CODE UPDATE for SANDBOX link

```
import { useForm } from "./useForm";

export const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
  // const formValues = { email: "", password: "" };

  const start = function () {
    // -------------- important -------------------
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // -------------- important -------------------

      const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3003/login", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: formValues.email,
          password: formValues.password
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      });

      const data = await resp.json();

      resolve(data);
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    // -------------- important -------------------
    console.log("Submitting");
    e.preventDefault();

    const t = await start();
    console.log(t);
    // -------------- important -------------------

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          autoComplete="off"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          name="email"
          value={formValues.email}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          required
        />
        <input
          autoComplete="off"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          name="password"
          value={formValues.password}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          required
        />

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is working, I have commented some part for faster development, you an un comment them and move forward. Now they should work.

Now you will surely have values being assigned to "t". Make sure you do some error handling, And then you can pass this token to the main function, You can either use the callback method or you can use Global context and manage the state in a better manner.

Let me know if it still fails, we can figure out a better solution.
Happy coding.

Comment: If it keeps failing me with the same error, because what I want to do is store it and then be able to unstructured the object

Comment: Hi @fanjiooJr, i am not able to get the comment.

Comment: Also it will be nice, if you can put it in a sandbox.io and use some dummy API to work with, as it will be easier to help.

Comment: I am making a login and the post returns a token within the ``resp`` if the email and password are correct. So what I need is to deconstruct the object obtained, so I have to store my information in some variable. As it looks there in you, but this error is throwing me ``Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.``

Comment: Can you update your de structuring logic ?

Comment: Here I leave the codebox for you to see. But that's the way it is basically.
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mahavira-gwbck?from-embed

Comment: Hi @fanjiooJr, i have added in a latest code snippet, this will work. It is working and i am able to see the form being rendered.